# A digger or an academic

Tags: meaning, british-english

In one of Jeffery Archer's Prison Diary books (written ca. 2002) he asks a fellow inmate, a PhD student, whether he is "a digger or an academic".

What is the meaning of "digger" in this context? I see occasional use of the term "goal digger", an obvious play on "gold digger", presumably someone who just wants collect the credential versus one who intends to pursue a career in academia.

Would that be a correct guess as to the meaning?

Comment: I can't be sure without more context (it would at least be useful to know what the PhD was in), but I'd be surprised if he meant "gold-digger". It's more likely he was differentiating between drudge-work (or physical labour) and intellectualism, maybe between the sort of PhD that's a mundane slog through data and the sort that's based on deep thinking.

Comment: @StuartF Edited to add the subject- marine anthropology. Thanks.

Comment: In this world, there's two kinds of people ... those with loaded programs, and those who dig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to refer to archeologists, anthropologists, etc  that *collate* data coming from the field, as opposed to those actually *gathering* data in the field.

**'Diggers'** go out into the field with a small shovel, pick and various sized brushes to find new (fresh*)  stuff, while **'academics'** mostly sit in comfortable air-conditioned labs analyzing the data...

Diggers are on  ['digs'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeological_excavation) most of the year, doing the dusty back-breaking excavations, while  many academics go on digs only  once a year, or when on sabbatical.

Although the cooperation between the 2 groups is essential for scientific reasons, there is often a certain rivalry and sometimes a mutual disdain; hence the "whether he is 'a digger or an academic'".

---

*fresh means right out of  the ground, no matter its position in history.

Comment: Oh, that's very good. For some reason the more literal interpretation didn't occur  to me- probably because it was "anthropology" and not "archaeology".

Comment: Then there's the geophys department, allegedly despised by both (_Maxwell's Grave_, M J Trow)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  OK...you have piqued my interest...

Comment: The Maxwell series is well worth reading. The star is Metternich.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, [this is fiction?](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=maxwell+metternich) Is it a good read?

Comment: (a or b) No, the more lethal Metternich. (b or a) Yes, written by M J Trow ([see Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._J._Trow)). Detective / humorous/wry/dry / inventive. (c) IMO, very good (but I don't rate the 'Lestrade' series. Especially with Rupert Graves' as the archetypal rendition.)